# Changing how values from object's attribute are displayed on print within a class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I have a class where I initialize a deck of 52 cards for a game of Texas Holdem Poker, and then draw a random number of cards from the deck, dependant on the number of players:

```
class Cards:
    def __init__(self):
        suits = ['s', 'c', 'd', 'h']
        values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
        deck = set(itertools.product(values, suits))
        self.drawn_cards = random.sample(deck,(5 + 2 * number_of_players))
```

However when printing the cards, I would like for 11 to be replaced with 'J', for 12 to be replaced with 'Q', and so on. I'm at a loss as to how to do it. After doing some searching on here I ended up adding this to the class:

```
def __str__(self):
        text = ""
        for x, y in self.drawn_cards:            
            if x == 11:
                text = "J"
            elif x == 12:
                text = "Q"
            elif x == 13:
                text = "K"
            elif x == 14:
                text = "A"
            else:
                text = x
```

But when I initialize an object (dealer):

```
dealer = Cards()
```

And then print the drawn cards:

```
print(dealer.drawn_cards)
```

I just get:

```
[(4, 'h'), (14, 'd'), (13, 's')........]
```

Instead of the desired:

```
[(4, 'h'), ('A', 'd'), ('K', 's')........]
```

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You are printing `dealer.drawn_cards` which is a list. Try printing your class instance: `print(dealer)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the cards and not invoking its `__str__`; either way, since `__str__` isn't returning a string in your implementation, it's going be an error.

The easiest solution would be to create a class level mapping that holds numbers-cards for the range `[11, 14]` and then create an intermediate translated list of tuples in its `__str__` and return its string representation:

```
class Cards:

    # translate numbers to cards
    _tr = {11: 'J', 12 :'Q', 13: 'K', 14: 'A'}

    def __init__(self):
        suits = ['s', 'c', 'd', 'h']
        values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
        deck = set(itertools.product(values, suits))
        self.drawn_cards = random.sample(deck,(5 + 2 * number_of_players))

    def __str__(self):
        r = [(x, y) if x not in self._tr else (self._tr[x], y) for x,y in self.drawn_cards]
        return str(r)
```

Now, printing your instance will yield the desired  result:

```
dealer = Cards()

print(dealer)
[(9, 'c'), ('A', 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'd'), (4, 's'), ('J', 'c'), (6, 'h'), ('A', 's'), (10, 'c')]
```